# What happens to foreground activity when the device reboot

Tags: android, android-activity, android-reboot

Will the onDestroy method be performed?
I want to do something before activity gets killed, can I write the code in onDestrory?

Comment: And what documentation says? *Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.